# How to solve error duplicate sources.list?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, apt-get, apt

sudo apt-get update throws me this error

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_trusty-pgdg_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/apt.postgresql.org_pub_repos_apt_dists_trusty-pgdg_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
miravm@ubuntu:/var/lib/apt/lists$
```

---

I belive this is related to postgres. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: This is not related to Postgres, or to programming, and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should easily be able to find a hundred duplicates on [ubuntu.se] and several of our other sister sites [su], [sf], and [unix.se]

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

after you have sources.list open remove

```
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
```

if you have a 32 bit system

or

```
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg/main i386 Packages
```

if you have a 64 bit system